# Iterating through files with OpenCV, files not found: can't open/read file: check file path/integrity

Tags: python, path

I try to patchify some pictures in python. Everything works fine if I load a single picture. But if I try to iterate through a dictionary I get following error in the python-console:

> [ WARN:0@2123.719] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp
> (239) cv::findDecoder imread_('001.jpg'): can't open/read file: check
> file path/integrity

My Code:

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import patchify as patchify

path ='C:/Users/j.brandstaeter/Desktop/Masterarbeit/graz/original_test/'
files = os.listdir(path)

for file in files :
    img = cv2.imread(file)
    cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.cvt.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    patches_img = patchify(img,(512,512,3),step=512-64)
        for i in range(patches_img.shape[0]):
            for j in range(patches_img.shape[1]):
                single_patch_img = patches_img[i,j,0,:,:,:]
                if not cv2.imwrite(
                        'C:/Users/j.brandstaeter/Desktop/Masterarbeit/graz/patches/images/' + '000' + '_' + str(i) + str(j) + '.jpg',
                    single_patch_img):
                raise Exception("failed!")
```

I am fairly new to programming/python and very grateful for any advise.

Comment: You should debug your code. Specifically put a breakpoint in the line: `img = cv2.imread(file)` and make sure that the filename in `file` is actually a valid image file.

Comment: `assert os.path.exists(file), os.getcwd()` learn how file paths work.

Comment: not an opencv issue. you just didn't look at the value of `file`